# How do I fix "Error calling method on NPObject!" when invoking methods on a signed applet from within javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, applet, jnlp

I am using a java applet that performs functionality that requires access outside the browser sandbox.  The applet is prepared as follows:

- All calls requiring privileged access are wrapped appropriately in calls to `AccessController.doPrivileged()`.
- The jar is signed and includes a certificate chain that validates with `jarsigner -verify` (output is "jar verified.").
- The MANIFEST.MF in the jar contains:

  `Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Created-By: 1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation)
  Permissions: all-permissions`
- The jnlp file contains:

      `<security>
              <all-permissions />
      </security>`
- The applet is deployed using `dtjava`:

  `dtjava.embed({
          id: 'myapplet',
          url: 'myapplet.jnlp',
          width: 1,
          height: 1,
          placeholder: "appletPlaceholder",
        },
        {},
        {
          onJavascriptReady: mycallback,
        }
      );`

  - In the callback, I call a method on the applet:

    `var applet = document.getElementById(appletId);
    applet.someMethod();`

Everything works as expected--but only if the base URL that is serving the applet (e.g., http://www.example.com/) is added to Java's "Exception Site List" within the Java control panel.

If the base URL is not listed in the Exception Site List, then I get the following error from the javascript when someMethod() is called:
`Error calling method on NPObject!`

This is cryptic, and I'm not sure how to track down the cause of the problem.

How do I fix this error?  How do I even debug this error?